# Using jDateChooser in SQL query

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, jdatechooser

I'm working on a little exercise, using *ORACLE HR database* and *Netbeans*, and I want to calculate difference between two `jDateChooser` values using a search button, here is a screenshot of my *jFrame* which explains everything, including my output error :

[image: http://prnt.sc/d7k538]

And here is my code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class Exercise extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     Connection Con = myConn.getCon();
     Statement St = null;
     ResultSet Rs = null;

     String tab[] = {"LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "JOB_TITLE", "DEPARTMENT_NAME", "SALARY"};
     DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(tab, 0);

    public Exercise() {
        initComponents();

        jTable1.setModel(dtm);

        fill_combo_job();
        fill_combo_dept();

        int Rc = dtm.getRowCount();
        row_count_label.setText(Integer.toString(Rc));
    }

    public void fill_combo_job(){

             try{
             //Getting data from table JOBS

             St = Con.createStatement();
             Rs = St.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT JOB_ID FROM JOBS");

             //Filling our jcombobox

             while(Rs.next()){
                 job_id_combo.addItem(Rs.getString("JOB_ID"));
             }

         }catch(Exception ex){

             System.out.println(ex.toString());
    }
    }

    private void fill_combo_dept(){

        try{

            St = Con.createStatement();
            Rs = St.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IS NOT NULL ORDER BY DEPARTMENT_ID");

            while(Rs.next()){
                dept_id_combo.addItem(Rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }

    }

    private void search_btn(){

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date1 = df.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
        String date2 = df.format(jDateChooser2.getDate());



        try{

   St = Con.createStatement();
   Rs = St.executeQuery("SELECT e.LAST_NAME, e.FIRST_NAME, j.JOB_TITLE, d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, e.SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES e, JOBS j, DEPARTMENTS d "
   + "WHERE j.JOB_ID = e.JOB_ID "
   + " AND d.DEPARTMENT_ID = e.DEPARTMENT_ID"
   + " AND j.JOB_ID = "+job_id_combo.getSelectedItem().toString()+" AND e.DEPARTMENT_ID = "+dept_id_combo.getSelectedItem().toString()
   + " AND HIRE_DATE BETWEEN TO_CHAR ('"+date1+"', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND TO_CHAR('"+date2+"', 'dd/MM/yyyy')"
   + " AND SALARY > "+salary_field.getText());

   while(Rs.next()){

    dtm.addRow(new Object[]{Rs.getString("LAST_NAME"), Rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"),
    Rs.getString("JOB_TITLE"), Rs.getString("DEPARTMENT_NAME"), Rs.getInt("SALARY")});
            }

            Con.close();
            St.close();
            Rs.close();


        }catch(Exception ex){

            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }


    }

    public void reset_form(){

        job_id_combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
        dept_id_combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
        salary_field.setText("");


    }
```

Comment: Consider these things while posting:
1) Post Minimal Question 2) Post only problematic piece of code). Also your screenshot says something different, your Question say something different. It's nothing to do with jDateChooser as the problem is with AC_MGR. Understand your problem before posting.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means there is something wrong with your query. Typo, incorrect quotes, incorrect capitalization.